# How to echo random line from text file?

Tags: php

i need to echo random lines from a text file like so

textfile.txt

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
line 6
```

index.php

```
line 4
```

im not great at php so any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: How great do you have to be to search the documentation for functions related to random numbers?

Comment: Down-voted as not enough research made. I found the answer to this question in 20-seconds using Google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this quite easily using the [`file`](http://php.net/file) and [`array_rand`](http://php.net/array_rand) functions:

```
$lines = file($filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
echo $lines[array_rand($lines)];
```

1. `file` returns an array of all the lines of the file and stores it in `$lines`.
2. `array_rand` picks a random index from the `$lines` array and the item at that index is echoed.

Comment: not recommended for a *large* file